# JavaScript Validation for Balance Amount

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have MySQL Table that consist of initial_amount, used_amount & balance as follows.

```
fin_code    initial_amount  used_amount balance
1    500,000.00      275,000.00      225,000.00 
2    212,000.00      125,000.00      87,000.00 
3    455,000.00      455,000.00      -
```

02) If I enter to issue 300,000.00 as used_amount through the Bootstrap view under fin_code 1, there need to control over issues vs balance. That is 225,000.00.

03) I used the following JavaScript code to perform this task

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#used_amount', function () {
        var bal = parseFloat($('#balance').val());

        var amount = parseFloat($('#used_amount').val());

        if (bal < amount) {
            $('#save').prop('disabled', true);

           $('#used_amount_div').addClass('danger');
           alert("Can not proceed your request ..!!. Issue amount is higher than the available balance..");
        } else {
            $('#save').prop('disabled', false);

        }
```

04) But it is properly working for the minus values / balances only. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can any one help me on this task ?

Comment: Where does MySQL factor in here? Remember that you *must* do server-side validation as well and that validation *must* not be subject to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the issue, would it be possible to re-word it?

Comment: @Raptord. when it issue any amount it will be added to the used_amount.